# Color Box for youtube

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I am using color box plugin to embed youtube videos but it doesn't seem to work. see my code below which is very basic.
`$(document).ready(function(){
               $('.youtube').colorbox({iframe:true, innerWidth:640, innerHeight:390});`

Then the code that opens the ovelay;

```
<p><a class="youtube" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0sRXkKe9SJk">Test Video</a></p>
```

When i replace the code above with the demo link and code, it works just fine. The code below works.
`<p><a class="youtube" href=" http://www.youtube.com/v/VOJyrQa_WR4?rel=0&amp;wmode=transparent">Test Video</a></p>`

What am i missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="path/to/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/colorbox.css" />
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".youtube").colorbox({iframe:true, innerWidth:640, innerHeight:390});
});
</script>

<p><a class='youtube' href="http://www.youtube.com/v/0sRXkKe9SJk?rel=0&amp;wmode=transparent">Play My Video</a></p>
```

Comment: Don't forget to update the path to `jquery.colorbox.js` and `colorbox.css`

Comment: Thanks mate. I had tried this initially but it didn't work but now it does from your code, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same issue:  The dialog would open and I could see it connect to youtube, but the video would not respond to the "Play" button.
I added a parameter, autoplay=1, to the string and it works fine now.